# The minimum norm solution of linear equation and inner product

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

this is my first time to post a question there. I want to know some details about L1-KPCA algorithm.
https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0031320312002877?token=0AAA357BE4D5B95D98C9707EF5904C9F3B6BF2AACDC2D18977345FB788D9FC61BB1DF76C6AE73C476BC9551E6774D4F1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cViJX.jpg)

The code is shown about the lower layer algorithm as follows.

```
import numpy as np

def L1KPCA(K,a0):
    N=np.shape(K)[0]
    # Initialization (Step I)
    a0=a0/np.sqrt((a0.T.dot(K)).dot(a0))
    flag=1
    iteration=0
    p=np.zeros((1,N))
    ep=1e-6
    while flag==1:
        iteration=iteration+1
        ## Step 2
        a0_K=a0.T.dot(K)
        p=np.where(a0_K<0,-1,1)
        ## Step 3
        columnsum=np.zeros((N,1))
        for i in range(N):
           columnsum=columnsum+p[i]*K[:,i]
            ##---------question here---------------
        U,D,V=nop.linalg.svd(K,full_matrices=False)
        ita=(V.dot(linalg.pinv(np.diag(D))).dot(U.T)).dot(columnsum)
        a=a/np.sqrt((ita.T.dot(K)).dot(ita))
        ## Step 4
        if np.sqrt((a-a0).T.dot(a-a0))>ep:
           a0=a
        ##---------question here---------------
        ## want to check zero results yield by inner product
        elif a.T.dot(K)==0:
           da=np.random.rand(N,1)*ep
           a0=(a+da)/np.sqrt((a+da).T.dot(a+da))
           flag=1
        else:
           flag=0
```

http://www.sci.utah.edu/~gerig/CS6640-F2012/Materials/pseudoinverse-cis61009sl10.pdf

My question is in step 3 and 4. 
In step 3, to find the minimum norm solution of \ita, I use svd here. Is it correct? Is it possible to use np.linalg.pinv(K) here.

In step 4, I write a.T.dot(K)==0 to check inner product among the N column of K. Is it correct here. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you get errors running the code? Does your output come out unexpected? As stated, I'm not sure if this question is on topic for SO. The best way to check if you implemented an algorithm correctly is to verify known input/output pairs, not ask some strangers on the internet to look it over. If the output is incorrect, and you explained how, said strangers might be a good resource to help you though.

Comment: @ Mad Physicist Thanks for your reply. This the demo code that I want to know the judgment step 3 and 4 are correct or not. Here the rank of matrix K is not full rank. Many problems usually occurs here.

Comment: Did you run the code?